# WordPress WP_User_Query($args) using Where and Like

Tags: wp-user-query

I wish to return a WP user list in my plugin where the email address matches @mydomain.com. The user list I am after is for all mydomain.com users.

Does anyone have a code snipit for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://wpusersplugin.com/ It does a lot with user lists and you could probably dig into the code to find some help.

Answer (score 4):

The search parameter can take an email address and can also accept wildcards:

```
$wp_user_search = new WP_User_Query( array( 'search' => '*@mydomain.com' ) );
$users = $wp_user_search->get_results();
```